# SQL query for passing xml into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an Xml file that i am trying to parse into database tables.

I have some code which does that.. however it doesn't organise the code into the tables appropriately as it returns all products and rooms without any order.

As you can see from below, the xml first defines the room name and RoomId.

What follows then is a list of products that are going to be in that room. 
These **products** are all stored within a tables and have been assigned parent and child ids.

The XML then repeats this structure for a different room.

I have taken some of the code out as there is a lot of styling and unnecessary code.

What I would like is a query that can store this data appropriately so that I can store it in the database and then retrieve it in SQL Server Report builder.

cheers

**XML**

**Name spaces**

```
<t:RadDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 

xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 

xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 

xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 

xmlns:custom1="clr-namespace:TAS2;assembly=RadRichTextBoxExtensions" 

xmlns:custom2="clr-namespace:;assembly=RadRichTextBoxExtensions" version="1.2" LayoutMode="Paged" LineSpacing="1" LineSpacingType="Auto" ParagraphDefaultSpacingAfter="30" ParagraphDefaultSpacingBefore="30" SelectedBibliographicStyleName="\APA.XSL" StyleName="defaultDocumentStyle">
```

**XML snippet**

```
<custom1:RoomGroupRangeStart  RoomID="26" RoomName="Bathroom" />
<custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="48" Level="1" Name="Plumbing"    ParentID="1"/>
</custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
<custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="49" Level="2" Name="Central Heating" ParentID="48" />
</custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
<custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="50" Level="3" Name="Gas" ParentID="49" />
</custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
```

**First attempt**

```
select 
    nodes.node.value( '@ID', 'int' ) Id,
    nodes.node.value( '@Name', 'varchar(max)' ) Name,
    nodes.node.value( '@ParentID', 'int' ) ParentId
from    
    @xml.nodes( '//*:Products' ) nodes ( node )


select
    nodes.node.value ( '@RoomID', 'int' ) RoomID,
    nodes.node.value ( '@RoomName', 'varchar(max)' ) RoomName
from    
    @xml.nodes( '//*:RoomGroupRangeStart' ) nodes ( node )
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Apologies ... Sql server

Comment: This is not a valid XML document - there's no single root element. And also: there are obviously XML namespaces in play (judging from the `custom1:` prefix) - but those aren't visible - most likely because parts of the XML document are missing ...

Comment: I just re-read this and think, that my answer will not fit to your needs. If you paste several similar blocks one below each other the output is no more as expected... It is really bad, that your `RoomGroupRangeStart` does not cover the full details as nested elements. What is the `ParentID`? Plumbing has "1", but this is obviously not the related RoomID. Is there any connection between Product and Room?

Comment: Hi Simula, I just edited my answer as such: The Nodes are numbered. Starting with a DistinctRooms CTE, you can than pick the Nodes with their RowInx between "their" Room and the next Room Index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

I added a root node with dummy namespaces and several more repeated structures...

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<t:RadDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 
                xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 
                xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Revisions;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 
                xmlns:n="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Notes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" xmlns:th="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Themes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" 
                xmlns:custom1="clr-namespace:TAS2;assembly=RadRichTextBoxExtensions" 
                xmlns:custom2="clr-namespace:;assembly=RadRichTextBoxExtensions" version="1.2" LayoutMode="Paged" LineSpacing="1" LineSpacingType="Auto" ParagraphDefaultSpacingAfter="30" ParagraphDefaultSpacingBefore="30" SelectedBibliographicStyleName="\APA.XSL" StyleName="defaultDocumentStyle">
  <custom1:RoomGroupRangeStart RoomID="26" RoomName="Bathroom" />
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="48" Level="1" Name="Plumbing" ParentID="1" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="49" Level="2" Name="Central Heating" ParentID="48" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="50" Level="3" Name="Gas" ParentID="49" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>

  <custom1:RoomGroupRangeStart RoomID="27" RoomName="Test" />
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="48" Level="1" Name="Test1" ParentID="1" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="49" Level="2" Name="Test2" ParentID="48" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="50" Level="3" Name="Test3" ParentID="49" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>

  <custom1:RoomGroupRangeStart RoomID="28" RoomName="OneMore" />
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="48" Level="1" Name="OneMore1" ParentID="1" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="49" Level="2" Name="OneMore2" ParentID="48" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
  <custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
    <t:Products HasChild="True" ID="50" Level="3" Name="OneMore3" ParentID="49" />
  </custom1:SemanticRangeStart.Product>
</t:RadDocument>';
SELECT @x;
```

You query it like this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents' AS t
                  ,'clr-namespace:TAS2;assembly=RadRichTextBoxExtensions' AS custom1
                  ,DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation')
,Numbered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowInx
          ,CASE WHEN The.Node.value('fn:local-name(.)','varchar(max)') = 'RoomGroupRangeStart' THEN 'Room' ELSE 'Product' END AS NodeType
          ,CAST('<node>' + CAST(The.Node.query('.') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '</node>' AS XML) AS TheNode
    FROM @x.nodes('/t:RadDocument/*') AS The(Node)
)
,DistinctRooms AS
(
    SELECT Numbered.*
          ,TheNode.value('(*//@RoomID)[1]','int') AS RoomID
          ,TheNode.value('(*//@RoomName)[1]','varchar(max)') AS RoomName 
    FROM Numbered
    WHERE NodeType='Room'
)

SELECT 
       dr.*
      ,RelatedProducts.TheNode.value('(*//@HasChild)[1]','bit') AS HasChild
      ,RelatedProducts.TheNode.value('(*//@ID)[1]','int') AS ProductID
      ,RelatedProducts.TheNode.value('(*//@Level)[1]','int') AS Level
      ,RelatedProducts.TheNode.value('(*//@Name)[1]','varchar(max)') AS ProductName
      ,RelatedProducts.TheNode.value('(*//@ParentID)[1]','int') AS ParentID

FROM DistinctRooms AS dr
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT products.*
    FROM Numbered AS products
    WHERE products.NodeType='Product'
      AND products.RowInx BETWEEN dr.RowInx AND (SELECT ISNULL(MIN(x.RowInx),1000000) FROM DistinctRooms AS x WHERE x.RowInx>dr.RowInx )
) AS RelatedProducts;
```

the result

```
1   26  Bathroom    1   48  1   Plumbing         1
1   26  Bathroom    1   49  2   Central Heating 48
1   26  Bathroom    1   50  3   Gas             49
5   27  Test        1   48  1   Test1            1
5   27  Test        1   49  2   Test2           48
5   27  Test        1   50  3   Test3           49
9   28  OneMore     1   48  1   OneMore1         1
9   28  OneMore     1   49  2   OneMore2        48
9   28  OneMore     1   50  3   OneMore3        49
```

Comment: That looks good, however I am unable to make any changes to the xml. I will receive it as a document that I want to parse ... Sorry

Comment: @Simula There's no need to make changes to the XML. I just created a test scenario to get this running ...

Comment: Ah ok apologies... If they are numbered would it cause any issues if each doc is slightly different ? Ie room may have more products on doc a than on doc b?

Comment: I have a copy of one here. I'm getting an scalar variable declaration error line 9. I've declared the xml at the bottom as @x? Any ideas

Comment: @Simula I don't get it. Just replace the upper block of my answer with your XML.  Then try SELECT @x This must work before you can test it.  Then copy my second block below and test

Comment: @Simula Your XML should have a root node. You'll have to adapt the XPath expressions slightly

Comment: hi, its looking good! .. apart from i cant get anything to return.. have changed a few things but no luck yet...

so basically my root is a a rad document tag.. i switched root to this and got rid of some errors. now i think the issue maybe with the  with the  XMLNAMESPACES
('custom 1' AS t
 ,'custom 2' AS custom1
  ,DEFAULT 'urn1'

instead i have the following 

lines like the following :

xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents"

Comment: @Simula There are some lines before the part you've posted - probably. Please paste them into your question ...

Comment: should i change the names spaces from urn to these ?

Comment: @Simula Yes, and the nodes' XPath in "Numbered" to the correct path which is not "root" probably ...

Comment: how would i do this? it doesnt wan aplay game with me

Comment: WITH XMLNAMESPACES
<t:RadDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" as 'a'
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" as 'b'
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.Styles;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents" as 'c'

Comment: @Simula No ... please edit your question and add the full XML- intro to your sample XML.  I'll help you through ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your help but I can't put the full xml on as there's a lot of information that I have left out on purpose due to privacy etc.  I can get the field names back but with no data.  I can see how you call the name spaces from the xml but I can't get mine to work.

Comment: @Simula, OK... If you just add the root element with the namespace declarations to the XML in your question this should suffice...

Comment: I've just added the name spaces

Comment: @Simula, for testing purpose you might try to change your XML as such, that your content is wrapped within `<root>Your XML</root>` and try it then. If it works, you''ll just have to find out how the namespaces work...

Comment: @Simula, look at my edited answer. Good luck. I'll have a look into this tomorrow again...

Comment: @Simula, Btw: I just pushed you over the magic 15 reputation points to make you able to vote on answers :-)

Comment: Hey! I have changed the namespaces and update the root nose as advised, there's no errors but I'm only getting the field names back with no data. Have i forgot something?

Comment: I should add that I have also tried encapsulating my xml in <root> brackets but still no difference

Comment: @Simula, How could I help you? I understand, that you don't want to post the XML due to privacy reasons, but: I'd need your XML from the very first character down to the first data elements - not the full xml... as this is getting rather long :-) (and takes quite some of my time...) it would be kind to open a new question for this (which offers a chance for me to earn new reputation points) and it will draw attention and call in other helpers... Please place a link to your new question here. Good luck and happy coding!